# Is it possible to fetch the image tag from a deployment in EKS using terraform kubernetes provider?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, terraform-provider-kubernetes, terraform-provider-helm

Context:
I'm reusing `terraform` modules and I deploy microservices using `helm` provider within terraform.

Problem:

I'm trying to translate this line into terraform code, to get the current image tag live from prod (in the interest of reusing it). I'm already using kubernetes provider's auth and doesn't make sense to pull kubectl in my CI just for this.

`k get deploy my-deployment -n staging -o jsonpath='{$.spec.template.spec.containers[:1].image}'`

Kubernetes terraform provider doesn't seem to support `data` blocks nor helm provider `outputs` blocks.

Does anyone know how could we get (read) the image tag of a deployment using terraform?

EDIT:

My deployment looks like this:

```
resource "helm_release" "example" {
  name       = "my-redis-release"
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "redis"
  version    = "6.0.1"

  values = [
    "${file("values.yaml")}"
  ]

  set {
    name  = "image.tag"
    value = "latest"
  }

}
```

The tag will be a hash that will change often and passed on from another repo.

`latest` in this case should be replaced by the current running tag in the cluster. I can get it using kubectl, using the line above, but not sure how using terraform.

Comment: Are you creating the Deployment with terraform? If so, you can define the output based on the resource. But I would need to see that part of the code. :)

Comment: yeah, I'm deploying using terraform via helm provider, but it doesn't look like helm provider supports outputs https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release

my deployment code's similar to the one from the example link ^

Comment: Outputs can be created with the arguments or attributes from the provider. Which example from that URL? It's pretty hard to reproduce what you want to achieve without any code.

Comment: You're right, I've updated post with an example.

Comment: In this case, I think there is no deployment specification in the chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there are multiple ways of doing it, where the easiest one for me is to reference the `set` argument of the `helm_release` resource:

```
output "helm_image_tag" {
  value = [ for setting in helm_release.example.set : setting.value if setting.name == "image.tag" ]
}
```

The output will then be a list where you can reference it in a shell script (or another scripting language):

```
  + helm_image_tag = [
      + "latest",
    ]
```

If the list format does not suit you, you can create a map output:

```
output "helm_image_tag" {
value = { for setting in helm_release.example.set : setting.name => setting.value if setting.name == "image.tag" }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
  + helm_image_tag = {
      + "image.tag" = "latest"
    }
```

By using `terraform output helm_image_tag` you can access this output value and decide what to do with it in the CI.

Comment: I feel it is worth adding that the third block of code relies on the semi-obscure fact that nested blocks in resources are technically `list(object)` despite not appearing that way intuitively in the DSL.

Comment: Yup, it's worth adding that, but please feel free to edit if you'd like.

Comment: This is great, thank you. Did not know you could use loops in outputs

Comment: If this answers your question, acceptance would be much appreciated.